# I can package for windows but I keep getting an error if I want to package for mac

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I built a small application using Vue,tailwindcss and electron and I was asked to package it for mac, packing for windows results in me getting a working app but when I try to package for mac I keep getting an error.(I am on windows 8.1)

I ran this command for Windows(this works):

```
"package-win": "electron-packager . Bitratemate --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=images/preflighticon4 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=StreamMyEvent --version-string.FileDescription=SME --version-string.ProductName=\"Bitrate Mate\""
```

and I tried this for mac:

```
"package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds"
```

```
const {app,Menu,BrowserWindow}= electron;
let mainWindow;
app.on('ready', function (){
    // Create new window
    mainWindow= new BrowserWindow({} );
      mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show()
      })
    mainWindow.loadURL(url)
```

Was expecting something similar to this:Wrote new app to release-builds\Bitratemate-win32-ia32 (its what I get when I package for windows)

but instead get this error:

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\Thijmen\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\symlink-test\test' -> 'C:\Users\Thijmen\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\symlink-test\testlink'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bitrate-mate@1.0.0 package-mac: `electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bitrate-mate@1.0.0 package-mac script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Thijmen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-12T09_20_57_337Z-debug.log
```

Comment: add 'sudo' may be due to admin rights on mac.

Comment: I am on windows, thanks for the advice tho

Answer (score 0):

You can't make `dmg` package from `window` if you are using [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) then you see they have already another package for `dmg`, [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-dmg) is link.